# Выбрать все дочерние подразделения с помощью Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Существует такая модель данных:

```cs
    public sealed partial class Department
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string NameDepartment { get; set; }

        public int ParentId { get; set; }

        public List<Worker> Workers => this.Dm.Worker.GetList().FindAll(x => x.DepartmentId == this.Id);

        public Department ParentDepartment => this.Dm.Department.GetItem(this.ParentId);

        public List<Department> ChildDepartments =>
```

Необходимо получить список дочерних подразделений (Связаны через ParentId) с помощью Linq. Я так понимаю здесь необходимо применить рекурсию и можно ли это сделать через свойство или придется создавать функцию? Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Без функции рекурсии не получишь, без рекурсии не обойдешь все уровни дочерних департаментов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. Мне помог вот этот вопрос на англоязычном StackOverFlow
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41608665/linq-recursive-parent-child

А именно, добавил метод расширения для Enumerable, чтобы работать с рекурсией.

```cs
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> SelectRecursive<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> selector)
    {
        foreach (var parent in source)
        {
            yield return parent;

            var children = selector(parent);
            foreach (var child in SelectRecursive(children, selector))
                yield return child;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Неплохо бы код метода поместить здесь в тело ответа.